# My Program not printing array by pointer arithmatic

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,count=0;
    cin>>a;
    int* arr;
    while(a)
    {
    int x= a%10;
    a=a/10;
    *(arr+count)=x;
    count++;
    }
    for(int i=0 ;i< count-1; i++)
    {
        cout<<*(arr+i);
    }
}
/* o/p :segementation error
// i/o :5*/
```

** array with pointers

> why segmentation error

partitioning int in int array  **

> segmentation error

Comment: which array? there is no array in your code.

Comment: `arr` is uninitialized.

Comment: @tkausl i thought  we can create array using pointers ...thats why array

Comment: @ShubhamJangam - You were misguided. Don't worry, we all were at some point. It's the legacy of C and C++.

Comment: `arr` is never initialised.   So the usages of `*(arr + count)` and `*(arr + i)` both give undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY actually that doesnt give compile time error which may then could have produced.

Comment: @ShubhamJangam - Nowhere is it specified that such a thing should give a compile time error. C++ doesn't hold your hand, and will gladly let you shoot yourself in both feet.

Comment: @ShubhamJangam Why should it give you compile error? Writing a program which compiles fine, but crashes immediately, is easy.

Comment: @ShubhamJangam - accessing the value of uninitialised variables gives undefined behaviour.   A compiler is not required to diagnose undefined behaviour.   That said, most compilers have an option to give warnings about such things - but that option is also disabled by default.   Read your compiler documentation to work out how to get such warnings.

Comment: @StoryTeller - actually, according to Bjarne Stroustrup, "C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off".

Comment: @Peter - That may be the vision Bjarne had in mind, but I don't think it's quite the reality.

Comment: @StoryTeller - such is life when behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for help... but following solution by me also seems helpful
.... If any suggestion... always welcome !!

Answer (score 3):

Accessing an uninitialized value has undefined behaviour (there are exceptions, but none that apply to your case).

`arr` is uninitialized:

> ```
> int* arr;
> ```

The value of `arr` is used here:

> ```
> *(arr+count)=x;
> ```

Therefore the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Comment: how to initialise it then ... I am noobie here

Comment: @ShubhamJangam Like this: `arr = address_of_an_array;`. Replace `address_of_an_array` with the address of the array that you wish to point to.

Comment: @ShubhamJangam use new and delete for dynamically allocating memory

Comment: @ShubhamJangam - Use `std::vector`

Comment: @ShubhamJangam  The correct syntax for declaring an array of int in C and C++ is:  `int arr[SIZE];` where SIZE is non-zero.

Comment: @ShubhamJangam to expand on Michaels comment: `SIZE` must be known at compile time in C++. If you need dynamic size, use `std::vector` like StoryTeller suggested.

Comment: @user2079303 Following code also seems helpfull .... if any suggestions... welcome :)

Comment: Thanks people for help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,count=0;
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    int* arr=&i;
    while(a)
    {
    int x= a%10;
    a=a/10;
    *(arr+count)=x;
    count++;
    }
    for(int i=0 ;i< count; i++)
    {
        printf("%d",*(arr+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**YES we can create dynamic array also like this   may be not a good practice but really helpful to save memory **

Comment: `int i;` is a single integer. It is not an array. `*(arr+count)=x;` has undefined behaviour for all other values than `count == 0`.

Comment: @user2079303 above program works fine...  i just want to collect separate integers from 'a' . no undefined behavious seems to be present also...... *(arr+count) is just getting contagious memory

Comment: the program may *appear* to "work fine", but that's just because you were unlucky. Just because the program "works" doesn't mean that the behaviour isn't undefined. There is no guarantee that your program would continue working if you change compilation options, swap the compiler, run on different cpu, or use different input ...

Comment: `*(arr+count)` is "just" getting *contiguous* memory **that you never allocated and therefore may be clobbered by other parts of your program ... or you may be clobbering the the memory that was used for something else**. If you "want to collect separate integers from 'a'", then what you need is an array (or some other data structure that represents a collection).